# Function shown as prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, oop, prototype

So as you can see I have a greeting function and similar to that the getsMarried function. However, getsMarried is shown as a prototype (colored green in VSCode, opposed to yellow). Is this because I use this.lastName? Because the tutorial I am learning from is also doing the same without it shown as a prototype.

```js
const personPrototypes = {
  greeting: function(){
    `$Hello there ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
  },
  getsMarried: function(newLastName){
    this.lastName = newLastName
  }
}

const mary = Object.create(personPrototypes)
mary.firstName = 'Mary'
mary.lastName = 'Williams'
mary.age = 30

mary.getsMarried('Wlii')

console.log(mary.greeting())
```

Comment: Maybe `greeting` is coloured differently because it doesn't do anything or change any properties? This isn't really a question for StackOverflow. Instead, check the VSCode docs or create an issue asking why the JavaScript syntax highlighter chooses different colours.

Comment: I asked here because it also doesn't function as it should. Maybe there's been some changes in JS since the tutorial was published (it's 3-4 years old).

Comment: Well, you're obviously missing the `return` from `greeting`. If you added that, it'd work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`console.log` does not show result as there is nothing to show. So we can `return` your greeting from the function to be shown in `console.log`.

[As mdn says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

> The return statement ends function execution and **specifies a value
> to be returned** to the function caller.

An example:

```js
const personPrototypes = {
  greeting: function(){
    return `$Hello there ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
  },
  getsMarried: function(newLastName){
    this.lastName = newLastName
  }
}

const mary = Object.create(personPrototypes)
mary.firstName = 'Mary'
mary.lastName = 'Williams'
mary.age = 30

mary.getsMarried('Wlii')

console.log(mary.greeting())
```

Comment: I realized I was missing "this" keyword in my greeting function and that's why I was getting undefined in the console. The function is still colored green though which confuses me, but I guess that's got something to do with VS Code.